# Copying specific ranges/cells on a standard template

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I fairly new to VBA, using it to work on simple macros to automatize my time.

I am looking for an Excel macro which copies specific cells, on different regions of a series of worksheets from the same template(see the image, I want to copy the, yellow, gray and green cells). All sheets work on the same workbook. The main quest is: Put it all together, as values, sequentially on one sheet, with just the same headers and put a total sum in the end of this columns. If it's simpler to keep/use the template and sum the values in there, ok for me too. If I've created 20 new sheets, the macro will read the already existed and the new sheets and consolidate it in the sheet "consolidated".

I've found a code that do almost everything I need, but I'm struggling to change de range on to copy regions I want.

Like I said, using the template (create a copy from the master template and summing the values in there?) or simply combining the value side by side, so every row represent a sheet, for me ok too.

Please, any help is welcomed, thanks in advance.

The code I used follows below [[source]](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win002.htm).

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "Consolidado" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidado").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "Consolidado"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "Consolidado"

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name And sh.Name <> "Menu" And sh.Name <> "Infos" And sh.Name <> "Log Update" And sh.Name <> "Master" Then

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)


            'Fill in the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            


            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
            'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

[The Excel Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng0Eu.jpg)

**EDIT**:

The results can be one of the 2 below, which is easier to do.

[Result sheet option 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgs4D.jpg)

[Result sheet option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p8wU.jpg)

**EDIT 2**

[Clean workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a1UlcEM597HP16NO_elwEjUAZbWKLEyY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: To clarify: You have n sheets that look as the "The Excel Template". Now you want to summarize the data from the sheets. How should the summary look? Is it just one value or should it look exactly like the template but each cell is the sum of all coresponding cells in the n sheets?

Comment: Yes, N sheets of the same Template.
Yes again, summarize each sheet in one row or sum all the values on the same cell the values has been entered/calculated.

Other things that might help in the understanding:
- Yellow cells are a list, the user choose one of the option, is a text cell.
- Gray cells are automated, have formulas in them. I just need the values of it.
- Green cells are values entered by the user.

The answer can be one of the options listed in the question, see it again please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many cells are to be summed?

Comment: As many as I want to create. The sheets: Menu, Log Update, Infos and Master are the ones I want to keep untoched.
There is a button I've created that copy the exact template, and users are advised that they can only edit this template.

Comment: Sorry you missunderstood me. How many grey,yellow and green cells are there, and is the number constant or will it frequently change?

Comment: Sorry sorry! Now i understand what you've said.
It work like this. After they pressed the button, they select the yellow cell, fill only the green cell and the values on the gray cells are calculated. The result, after the filled the green cells, are fix, they don't change.The result may vary from one cell to another in formatting, ones are general and other currency

Comment: Ok I write my thoughts as an answer so you can give feedback on as this would work for you

Answer (score 0):

After the clarification in the comments I would do as follows:

For simplicity lets take the following Template:

[image]

So you want Cell `A2` in Sheet `Consolidado` to be the sum of Cell `A2` of all the other sheets, and for the other cells respectivelly.

I propose the following: You create a sheet `Consolidado` from the template. You then fill the `valueCells` array with the list of cells you want to be summed up in the `Consolidado`sheet.

The code below then will go through the targeted sheets, and add the value from each cell in the array to an outputArray. After the targeted sheets are summed up, it is pasted to the `Consolidado` sheet
    Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set DestSh = wb.Sheets("Consolidado")

    valueCells = Array("A2", "C2", "A4", "B4", "C4")

    Dim outputArray As Double
    ReDim outputArray(UBound(valueCells))

    For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name And sh.Name <> "Menu" And sh.Name <> "Infos" And sh.Name <> "Log Update" And sh.Name <> "Master" Then
            For i = LBound(valueCells) To UBound(valueCells)
                outputArray(i) = outputArray(i) + sh.Range(valueCells(i))
            Next i
        End If
    Next sh

    For i = LBound(valueCells) To UBound(valueCells)
        DestSh.Range(valueCells(i)) = outputArray(i)
    Next i




End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. 
Tried it, but received Runtime Error 9. =/

I cleaned the workbook, i attached it, link in the question.

The values on Cell A2 are texts, like I said, depending on the way the result sheet come, I can have it or not.

The way you wrote, if each sheet will be on row, i should conserve the name in the yellow cell. If your summing the values, doesn't matter.

I made myself clear? I'm sorry if not, english is not my mother language.

I guess with the workbook you can get the idea i passing. Anything else you need to understand, just ask! Thx Again!

Comment: In the example above I am summarizing the values as a sum. Therefore you should only enter cells with numeric values to the "valueCells" array

Comment: Thank you, very very much for your help, but i could manage the problem and what I wanted with this other version of the code [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win003.htm), take a look. Now I can summarize it.  Again, thanks a lot for you help and support! Beste Regards!